# Blogger create Apple RSS Feed Gadget

Tags: rss, blogger, blogspot

I want to create a gadget for my blog that shows the Apple RSS Feed. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create a new gadget, please see the [documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/blogger/docs/gadgets/gadgets_for_blogger.html) on how to do this and then come back to Stack Overflow when you have a more directed question.  It's hard for us to help you much with such a broad question.

However, it sounds like you just want a gadget that displays a particular RSS feed.  In this case you just need to use the RSS Feed gadget that's already included in Blogger.  Just go in to configure your site, add a gadget to the sidebar or wherever you want it, and then specify the gadget to be the RSS Feed gadget.  You can then customize the gadget to point to a particular RSS feed, in this case the Apple one you want.

Comment: Thanks so much. Sorry, I didn't see the RSS Gadget.